# Set Product Custom Options From Observer Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, product, customization, magento-1.9

I am trying to add custom options to products on save. I want to add or update custom options (not additional options) on before_product save. I am able to access the observer and it is working on save as well but unable to update the custom options. Create option code is working if run from standalone script but not from observer only.
This is my observer code

```
`class Company_Module_Model_Observer{
    public function updateOptions($observer){
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $categories= $product->getCategoryIds();
        $currentCategory = '';

        foreach ($categories as $cat_id){
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
            $currentCategory = $cat->getName();
        }

        $skuList =['LAPTOP_','DESKTOP_'];
        $upgrades = $optionValues =  [];
        if($currentCategory=='Laptops'){
            $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'LAPTOP_%'));
            $upgrades = $_productCollection;
        }
        $meta = "6 this is product meta with custom plugin ".$product->getName();
        foreach ($upgrades as $products) {
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId());

            $optionValues = array(
                'title' => $_product->getName(),
                'price' => $_product->getPrice(),
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'sku' => $_product->getSku(),
                'sort_order' => 0,
            );
        }

        $options = array(
            'title' => 'Upgrades',
            'type' => 'drop_down',
            'is_required' => 0,
            'sort_order' => 0,
            'values' => $optionValues
        );
    
        $product->setMetaDescription($meta);
        $product->setProductOptions(array($options));
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        //if uncomment this then save loop continues and site hangs
        //$product->save();
    }
}`
```

No error in logs or anything else. Please guide me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are in an infinite loop because the observer relaunches the same function each time, so when you run the save product function ( $product->save(); ), your function is rerun, and so on.

If you use the event catalog_product_save_before observer, you don't have to run the save function.

otherwise here:

```
        foreach ($categories as $cat_id){
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
            $currentCategory = $cat->getName();
        }
```

You get the last category in the collection, is that correct?

Comment: I got your point about save loop. I tried without save then it runs completely but not saving the custom options. My actual concern is why the custom option is not saved

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but I had a similar issue like this a while back...
You are calling `$product->setProductOptions()` which without knowing your code I can only guess is setting it on the `$product`'s _data array, which is probably not what you want. You need to stick it on the `$product`'s option instance which will be used during the `$product->_afterSave()` call (You can see where the custom options are being saved in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product _afterSave() (~line 554 as of 1.9.4.5)). You can get the option instance like this: `$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance()` and set your options like this: `$optionInstance->addOption($options)`. After you do that you should be able to allow the save to continue and your custom options should be created.